# How can I display a JavaScript Object with Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I got a new project, where I'm building a complete new website.

Now I want to do my own captcha. For this I use the html2canvas library from [hertzen](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js).

So far, so good. I can convert fixed nodes which are on the main page and return them as an image. But what I'm trying to do now is to create a kind of "fake" node with JavaScript and return it as an image.

Here is what I tried:

```
image_string = getCaptchaCheck_code(image_string).split("\"");
image_string = image_string[3];
image_string = getCaptchaCheck_code(image_string)
let fakeObject = '<div id="talltweets">'+image_string+'</div>';

let temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = fakeObject;
let htmlObject = temp.firstChild;
        
html2canvas(htmlObject, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {     
        var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        document.getElementById("textScreenshot").setAttribute("src", screenshot);
        captcha = document.getElementById("textScreenshot").value;
    },
});

function getCaptchaCheck_code(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(this.atob(str)));
}
```

My actual result with my trie is an [empty picture](https://i.ibb.co/Hx3qgtX/Bild-2021-10-08-195656.png).

If needed, here is the image_string variable:

```
let image_string = "eyIxIjoiUEhVK2N6d3ZkVDQ4YVQ1YVBDOXBQanhwUGpVOEwyaytjenhpUGpROEwySStORHhwUGpROEwyaytWenhpUGpNOEwySSsifQ==";
```

I have the original for the HTML2Canvas from [here](https://www.labnol.org/code/20056-convert-text-to-images-with-javascript?fbclid=IwAR2nqEcFbF5-nL-LTo4zCeiynK9eknuBe9QndDmRguL4A_YRTrP3OXD938M).

So there you can see what the function is expected.

I would be happy if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by my own.

First of all I needed to split the `image_string` in element values. This is needed because the `image_string` is a fully string type. The values in turn are written then to an array for iteration.

```
    let image_string = "eyIxIjoiUEdJK1pUd3ZZajQ4ZFQ1UlBDOTFQanhwUGtVOEwyaytQSFUrZVR3dmRUNTBRVHgxUGpBOEwzVStQR2srZUR3dmFUNDhkVDVZUEM5MVBnPT0ifQ==";
    image_string = getCaptchaCheck_code(image_string).split("\"");
    image_string = image_string[3];
    image_string = getCaptchaCheck_code(image_string)
    var nodeText = ""+image_string+""
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'talltweets')
    var childDiv = document.createElement("div");
    
    var regex = /([<][\/][a-zA-Z0-9][>])/gm;
    var newstr = nodeText.replace(regex, " ")
    regex = /([<][a-zA-Z0-9][>])/gm;
    newstr = newstr.replace(regex, "")
    
    var letter = newstr.split(' ');
```

In the iteration I create new child nodes and write them together.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
        var node = nodeText[nodeText.indexOf(letter[i])-2];
        childNode = document.createElement(node);
        childNodeText= document.createTextNode(letter[i]);
        childNode.appendChild(childNodeText);
        newDiv.appendChild(childNode);
    }
```

After the iteration I created an placeholder div container in my HTML files.
Now the placeholder needs to be filled up.

```
    const placeholderElement = document.getElementById("eyIxI");
    placeholderElement.appendChild(newDiv);
```

I also pulled the `getCaptchaCheck_code` function up to make sure it is loaded before the `html2canvas` function.

```
    function getCaptchaCheck_code(str) {
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(this.atob(str)));
    }
    
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("talltweets"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById("textScreenshot").setAttribute("src", screenshot);
            placeholderElement.removeChild(newDiv);
        },
    });
```

As you can see in the last code, the `placeholderElement` will remove the "captcha text".

The code works now for 100%.

Enjoy.

Comment: By the way. Use the second HTML2Canvas JS library link. Unfortunately, version 2021 does not work in this case.